# getting number of values within reduceByKey RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

when reduceByKey operation is called, it is receiving list of values of a particular key. My question is:

1. are the list of values it receives in a sorted order?
2. is it possible to know how many values it receive?
3. i'm trying to calculate first quartile of the list of values of a key within reduceByKey. is this possible to do within reduceByKey?

Comment: I think you want groupByKey, although technically I believe you could mess around with reduceByKey to get this to work

Comment: i actually tried groupByKey, but i read here that it is less efficient if you are not passing the RDD for next step processing http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201402.mbox/%3CCAAqHKj7j9cKF6pYY750rP9WC68BUjd6Gxmozc+7HXkzhmRi_7w@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: That's correct it's not as efficient, but that's why it's more versatile

Answer (score 0):

.1. No, that would be totally going against the whole point of a reduce operation - i.e. to parallelalize an operation into an arbitrary tree of suboperations by taking advantage of associativity and commutativity.

.2. You'll need to define a new monoid by composing the integer monoid and whatever it is your doing.  Let's assume your operation is `op` then
.

```
yourRdd.map(kv => (kv._1, (kv._2, 1)))
.reduceByKey((left, right) => (left._1 op right._1, left._2 + right._2))
```

will give you an `RDD[(KeyType, (ReducedValueType, Int))]` where the `Int` will be the number of values the reduce received for each key.

.3. You'll have to be more specific about what you mean by first quartile.  Given that the answer to 1. is no, then you would have to have a bound that defines the first quartile then you won't need the data to be sorted because you could filter the values out by that bound.